# Pandas: break categorical column to multiple columns

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

Imagine a Pandas dataframe of the following format:

```
id  type  v1  v2
1   A     6   9
1   B     4   2
2   A     3   7
2   B     3   6
```

I would like to convert this dataframe into the following format:

```
id  A_v1  A_v2  B_v1  B_v2
1   6     9     4     2
2   3     7     3     6
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `set_index` to move the `type` and `id` columns into the index,
and then `unstack` to move the `type` index level into the column index. You don't have to worry about the `v` values -- where the indexes go dictate the arrangement of the values.

The result is a DataFrame with [a MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing) for the column index:

```
In [181]: df.set_index(['type', 'id']).unstack(['type'])
Out[181]: 
     v1    v2   
type  A  B  A  B
id              
1     6  4  9  2
2     3  3  7  6
```

Generally, a MultiIndex is preferable to a flattened column index. 
It gives you better ways to select or manipulate your data based on `type` or `v` value.

If you wish to reorder the columns to exactly match the order shown in the desired output, you could use `df.reindex`:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: x[::-1]))
```

yields

```
     v1 v2 v1 v2
type  A  A  B  B
id              
1     6  9  4  2
2     3  7  3  6
```

And if you wish to flatten the column index to a single level, then

```
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(t, v) for v,t in df.columns]
```

yields

```
    A_v1  A_v2  B_v1  B_v2
id                        
1      6     9     4     2
2      3     7     3     6
```