# unstack column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as:

```
rater audio rating
    a   n1   y1
    a   n2   y2
    b   n1   y3
    b   n2   y4
```

I want to split the column `rater` to get

```
audio rating_a rating_b 
  n1    y1    y3
  n2    y2    y4
```

I tried a code as in [Pandas: break categorical column to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990389/pandas-break-categorical-column-to-multiple-columns)

```
dftemp = dffinal.set_index(['rater', 'audio'])
dftemp.unstack(['rater'])
```

But this throws an error

```
Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

As mentioned in [Pandas unstack problems: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651079/pandas-unstack-problems-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-re)

I tried using `dftemp = dffinal.set_index(['rater', 'audio'],append=True)`
But this leads to lot of NaN values in the final output

```
      audio rating
rater      a    b
0    n1    y1  NaN
1    n2   NaN   y2
2    n1    y3  NaN
3    n2   NaN   y4
```

Similar question which I can't follow is:
[Pandas - unstack column values into new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840043/pandas-unstack-column-values-into-new-columns)

Thanks jezrael, the solution is:

```
dffinal.pivot_table(index='audio', columns='rater', values='rating')
```

Comment: `y1`, `y2` are strings? Then use `dffinal.pivot_table(index='rater', columns='audio', values='rating', aggfunc=','.join)`

Comment: if `y1, y2` are numbers change `aggfunc='mean'` or `aggfunc='sum'`